# Add CALayer to UILabel text

Tags: ios, uilabel, calayer

Is there a way to add extra CAShapeLayer( a small box) to uilalbel text. I want it to be placed exactly after the last character of label.

Thank you!
[some what like this. an extra layer near to the end of label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0WI.jpg)

Comment: add a  picture of how u want

Comment: Added a pic....

Comment: If that shape happens to be included in the [Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) you could avoid an extra layer altogether...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to go into complexity , try unicode characters & append it in your string with some space if required. You can check in Interface builder. Select label. Go into Edit -> Emoji & Symbols & select dot .Check in attached screenshot.

[image: Text with unicode char]

**EDIT**

Find position of last character in UILabel text & add CAShapeLayer as subview.It should work.

OR

You can simplify your solution by having 1 UIView with label & CAShapeLayer as subviews.Set origin of layer with label width .

Comment: but in my case i need to use calayer's animation.

Comment: I did your first solution with NSTextContainer and it did work perfectly for single line label any way for multiple lines..?

Comment: Do you want to add Dot after first line only or after every line in multiple line text?

Comment: never mind it worked... i dont know why it didnt work for the first time. Thanks

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation. I'll do when I have